# Replace multiple characters in a string with one char

Tags: c++, stl

What the best way to replace multiple characters in a string with one char?

```
string str("1   1     1");

//out: 1 1 1
```

Comment: Do you just want to make it so that all sequence of spaces just becomes a single space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str.erase(
    std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()),
    str.end());
```

This will work on more than just the spaces though.  For example, the string "aaabbbcccddd" would become "abcd".  Is that what you want?  If you just want to reduce the spaces to one space, you can pass a binary predicate as a third argument to `std::unique`, like this one:

```
bool BothAreSpaces(char lhs, char rhs)
{
    return (lhs == ' ') && (rhs == ' ');
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of standard algorithms!